# Setf and pushnew do not work on slot "options" of org-export-backend defined by cl-defstruct

Tags: org-export, cl

Org-mode export backends are defined as instances of the cl structure `org-export-backend`:

```el
(cl-defstruct (org-export-backend (:constructor org-export-create-backend)
                  (:copier nil))
  name parent transcoders options filters blocks menu)
```

The documentation string of `cl-defstruct` says:

> This macro defines a new data type called NAME that stores data
>   in SLOTs.  It defines a `make-NAME` constructor, a `copy-NAME`
>   copier, a `NAME-p` predicate, and slot accessors named `NAME-SLOT`.
>   You can use the accessors to set the corresponding slots, via `setf`.
>
> …
>
> Each SLOT may instead take the form (SNAME SDEFAULT SOPTIONS…), where
>   SDEFAULT is the default value of that slot and SOPTIONS are keyword-value
>   pairs for that slot.
>   Currently, only one keyword is supported, `:read-only`.  If this has a
>   non-nil value, that slot cannot be set via `setf`.

The `options` slot of `org-export-backend` is not marked with the keyword `:read-only`.

Therefore setting backend options with `cl-pushnew` should work as in the next example Elisp snippet:

```el
(require 'cl-lib)
(with-eval-after-load 'ox-ascii
    (cl-pushnew
     '(:ascii-upcase-title nil "ascii-upcase-title" 'org+-ascii-upcase-title)
     (org-export-backend-options (org-export-get-backend 'ascii))))
```

But this does not work reliable.
I had to remove it from [an answer to a question about the ox-ascii export plugin](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55801/in-org-mode-how-to-export-to-ascii-maintaining-capitalisation-of-the-heading).

If one calls <kbd>M-x</kbd> `load-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `ox-ascii` <kbd>RET</kbd> after this setting, one gets the error

```
let*: Symbol’s function definition is void: \(setf\ org-export-backend-options\)
```

This error presents itself with the following message if one tries to export with `org-export-dispatch`:

```
Problems while trying to load export back-end ‘ascii’
```

What does cause this error? How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macroexpansion of the body of `with-eval-after-load` happens eagerly, i.e. before `ox-ascii` is loaded.  So at that time, the slot is not defined and the `setf/cl-pushnew` macroexpander doesn't know what to do and chooses a default setter which is not the one that `cl-defstruct` will define.

Better move that code to a separate file:

```
(require 'ox-ascii)
(cl-pushnew
 '(:ascii-upcase-title nil "ascii-upcase-title" 'org+-ascii-upcase-title)
 (org-export-backend-options (org-export-get-backend 'ascii))))
```

and then load it when `ox-ascii` gets loaded:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'ox-ascii (load <myfile>))
```

Comment: What about just using `eval-after-load` here? Or even `(eval-after-load "..." '(byte-compile ...))`

Comment: @Drew: if your stomach can take it, be my guest.

Comment: @Drew Thanks Drew, I think your comment gives a hint for a solution in the init file. There one could just suspend the macro expansion until evaluation. I.e.: `(eval-after-load 'ox-ascii '(cl-pushnew ...))`. Is that okay?

Comment: @Tobias: Yes, that's what I meant. Not sure what you mean by "Is that okay?".

Comment: @Drew Looks like the right magic formula is `(eval-after-load '(eval '(cl-pushnew ...)))`. With `(eval-after-load '(cl-pushnew ...))` alone one is still hit by the eager expansion problem.